# Shortcut for execution command in Geany

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, geany

In geany I have the option to modify the execution commands:

[image]

Here I created a second command for java testing with junit. Is it possible to bind the second menu option to a shortcut key? By default only the first command is bound to F5. I would like to bind the second one to F6 or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Geany's manual is quite clear about [key-binding in build menu](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#build-menu-keyboard-shortcuts):

> Build menu keyboard shortcuts
>
> Keyboard shortcuts can be defined for the first two filetype menu
>   items, the first three independent menu items, the first execute menu
>   item and the fixed menu items. In the keybindings configuration dialog
>   (see Keybinding preferences) these items are identified by the default
>   labels shown in the Build Menu section above.
>
> It is currently not possible to bind keyboard shortcuts to more than
>   these menu items.

In your situation, the 2nd filetype menu item is free, and *shortcutable*. That make sense to use it for Java filetype.